# Scheme/racket, where do I find dc?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm working on a program using Racket, and I need to be able essentially draw something, and be able to change the drawing for a visual of playing connect 4.. Right now the closest I can manage is either have it create a new window every time something changes. To make the code not incredibly long I'll just use an example.

```
(require racket/gui/base)
(require racket/draw)
(define frame (new frame%
               [label "Connect 4 Visual Window"]
               [width 800]
               [height 600]))

canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]
         [paint-callback
          (lambda (canvas dc)
            (send dc set-scale 3 3)
            (send dc set-text-foreground "Black")
            (send dc draw-text "Welcome to Connect 4!" 50 0)
(send dc draw-rectangle
  30 30   
  200 145)  
)])
(send frame show #t)
```

So I would want to do this, and then I need to be able to change what's already there, not delete that canvas, not close the window and make a new one, change it and refresh the image. I keep seeing functions that look like I can do that, but all of them require me to pass "dc", and I have no idea what I'm supposed to put for that to get it to

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a simple interactive game in Racket, I would recommend using the [`2htdp/universe`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html) and [`2htdp/image`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html) libraries. You give the `big-bang` form some high-level event handlers (for keyboard and mouse input, and for time passing) and function that renders the world as an image. The library handles creating the window and canvas and wiring them up to your event handlers. For the rendering function, rather than issuing drawing commands, you make basic images using operators like `bitmap` or `rectangle` and then compose them using operators like `place-image`.

The `2htdp/universe` documentation is a little short on examples, because they're mostly in the textbook, [How to Design Programs, 2nd ed](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/) (readable online). The Prologue and Part 1 will give you an introduction to `big-bang` with examples.

---

If you want to do it the hard way, you get a `dc` argument, an instance of the [`dc<%>`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html) interface, as an argument to your paint-callback function. To update the canvas, change some state visible to your paint-callback function (eg using a global variable and `set!`) and then call the [`refresh`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/window___.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._window~3c~25~3e%29._refresh%29%29) method of the canvas (inherited from `window<%>`). The canvas will clear and then use the paint-callback function you gave it to redraw itself. That function should draw different things based on the new state it sees. It's probably a bad idea to try to draw to the canvas outside of the paint-callback function.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did exactly what was I intended.

Comment: If you liked this answer, click the check mark next to the answer, to give Ryan credit for a correct answer!